# Upgrading XenServer 6.2 to 6.5 or updating in general

Tags: linux, xenserver, citrix

Trying to get my XenServer to update, and want to upgrade it also to version 6.5. But cant figur out how. When i try to update using the XenCenter, i cant select the server itselfe when i get to that point?

Screeny of how far i got.
Link to screeny: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFoEI.png

But i cant make up why i cant select the server that i want to update. i also try to put it in maintance mode, and also turn offline all the VM's

Any pointers i will be glad for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the "upgrade" feature, not the "update" feature.  Update would be for e.g. a hotfix for 6.2.  To go from 6.2 to 6.5 use the Rolling Pool Upgrade approach instead.  However, a quick look at The Google shows this is a process with many complexities (including what you are using for backing storage, NFS or SAN) so you might want to peruse the rolling upgrade procedure from Citrix before you dive in to it: http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/38322-102-714672/XenServer-6.5.0_Installation%20Guide.pdf.

Comment: Really?.. ISNT this made as most other programs and operating systems, that i can just start an prosess for update and it does the full thing on its own????

Comment: I see you haven't worked with Windows-type products much. There is no logic/commonality of functionality, not even within the same product suite.  I'm just telling you what the vendor says.  You'd need to talk to them about the logic of it or lack thereof.

Comment: Dont thinkyou understand my question here. Read it again, and look at the screeny.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I'm doing.  This is what it should look like if you're doing the rolling pool upgrade:  http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1007627-xenserver-6-2-to-6-5-rolling-pool-upgrade-stuck

Comment: What media, http location do i use to do a 6.2 to 6.5 upgrade?

Comment: No idea here?...

Comment: You should have a login to get it from the website:  https://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenapp.html - this will send you to a location to download an ISO of the install media.

Comment: a login?... last time i try making an account/login they want money. 1 or 2 year on XenServer.. i not paying to run a linux server.

Comment: Well dang, first I sent you to the wrong link, so for anyone else finding this, the commercial option is this:  https://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenserver.html.  The Open Source/unsupported option is this:  http://xenserver.org/open-source-virtualization-download.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this process right now, and its painfully slow.

If you are upgrading a pool, start with the pool master.  Disable HA for the pool, and stop or migrate all VMs off to other pool members.

You have to boot the 6.5 installer CD directly, using physical media or some kind of remote-access card like drac / ilo / rsa / cimc card.

Then the installer prompts for "Upgrade or Clean Install"   Choose upgrade, and wait.  It asks very few questions compared to a full install.

Reboot once the install is completed and the machine will come up

*NOTE* this may appear broken on first boot.  DON'T PANIC - its shadow passwords.  Reboot the server into single user mode (type *menu.c32* at the bootloader prompt, press TAB to edit the xe entry and replace "quiet vga=785 splash" with  "single" then boot.    At the *sh#* prompt, run   *pwconv* and then    *echo newpassword | passwd --stdin root*   I use Dell DRACs which are renouned for putting in extra characters while typing.  This makes blind password changes "unnreliable"    Then reboot again and you should be able to connect to your server in xencenter.

If a single server, apply all the updates now like normal.

If you're a pool master, the pool will be visible again.  Evacuate the next node in the pool, and do the same reinstallation/upgrade from CD again.
Once the whole pool is on 6.5 then you can install updates.  Finally re-enable HA on the pool, if you want it.